# Assigning value based on another value in Excel

Tags: excel

My question must be very basic, but I'd like to ask it anyway.
How can I "tag" values in a column of one sheet (to be exact, those are Purchase Order numbers) so that another sheet can assign its own value ("received") based on that tag? It seems that there should be some condition-based rule.

I will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you mean, but assuming you want the values in one sheet to sum based on the values in another sheet - then yes this is pretty easy.
Add this formula to the sheet you want to do the counting in
=COUNTIF(OtherSheetName!C:C,"Purchase order")

If you mean that you want each individual cell to change, rather than deriving a total, then you must have some way of matching the cells in one sheet to the other sheet.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel! I will try to reformulate my question, because I am aiming for a different result.